# loading xcolor has conflict

Tags: beamer, color

I'm attempting to access more colors for `textcolor`:

```
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[NULL]
\usepackage{graphicx, textgreek, svg, longtable}
\usepackage [dvipsames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
```

but bizarrely, I get an error later on in the text:

```
/home/con/Documents/Presentations/.20220209.tex.swp:65: LaTeX Error: Option cla
sh for package xcolor.
```

All that line is, is `}`  Correct line numbering for errors is a known problem in LaTeX.

How can I access `dvispsames` with `xcolor`?

Comment: Load it as a beamer option.

Comment: Unrelated: in addition to xcolor, beamer also loads graphicx, so you don't need to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class `beamer` already loads package `xcolor`. LaTeX forbids loading a package twice with additional options the second time. Here, class `beamer` provides the class option `xcolor` to add additional options to package `xcolor`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
```

BTW, the `xcolor` option is called `dvipsnames` (derived from dvips + names).

Comment: We are working on the LaTeX restriction ...

Comment: @JosephWright I could imagine that a class/package defines an option in a special way with a marker, that the option definition contains code to be used at a later time. Then, the option parser of LaTeX can identify such options (that also might be key-value options), if they are given at a later call of `\usepackage` and execute the code instead of rejecting with an error. That will at least work for some suitable options of actively maintained packages without loss of compatibility of LaTeX's option handling.

Comment: More-or-less: see `ltkeys.dtx` in the development release. If a package uses the new mechanism (which we are still refining), the options are keyvals and if it's loaded a second time, we don't check for a clash but rather pass the options to the same keyval handler. So it's opt-in for packages but should work smoothly. I've set up `siunitx` to use this if available, although there's currently one bug which means it's not 100% smooth.